# Redirect to dashboard by user's group

Tags: cakephp, redirect, acl

I have acl based CakePHP app and users are belong to groups.

Please advice me where I should implement the redirection code by user's group:

- users belong to admin group redirect to `admin/dashboard`
- users belong to manager group redirect to `manager/dashboard`
- users belong to user group redirect to `user/dashboard`

Answer (score 0):

set `$this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;` in beforeRedirect() in users controller

In the login() function:

> ```
> if ($this->Auth->user()){
> $this->redirect(array('prefix'=>$this->Auth->user('group'),'controller'=>'dashboard','action'=>'index'));
>  }
> ```

This code is just example to show how it is done, not to be taken as-is.